# ExecutionEngineException only when debugging

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5, executionengineexception

I have C# code that throws ExecutionEngineException only when I debug it. When I just run it from Visual Studio without debugging (press the "Start without debugging") button, this piece of code works OK. But when I debug it from Visual Studio it throws ExecutionEngineException.

Due to this problem I cannot debug my application, as the code I am trying to debug is executed AFTER the problematic piece of code.

Here are some details:

- I am using Visual Studio 2012
- The main application is a C++/CLI application that calls my C# code
- The application runs for some time until it reaches the problematic lines of code in C#
- The relevant code is a query against an Entity Framework context.
- I am using Entity Framework 5
- The DB where my entities are stored is SQL Server LocalDB (the one that comes with VS2012)

**Edit**

Further investigation shows that the actual problem is an access violation exception that originates in the default constructor of System.Data.DataSet, which also happens if I just write `new DataSet()`.

**Edit 2**
I created a small application that demonstrates this problem. The source code can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4QQDeKuMr4eQ3IwZERmNTctbDQ/edit).

You are welcome to compile it and try and run the project `Application`. It should crash in `Adder.cs` with `ExecutionEngineException` when creating a new `DataSet`. Please note that the debugger should be Mixed and not Managed/Native.

Comment: Where does the ExecutionEngineException originate?

Comment: The stacktrace is null. According to VS, the highlighed line when the exception is thrown is the LINQ query itself.

Comment: There is also no InnerException.

Answer (score 4):

Your C++/CLI code is most likely corrupting the garbage collected heap.  A very typical way for unmanaged code to misbehave.  This doesn't get discovered until later, like when you new an object or the garbage collector runs.  So the code that crashes is completely unrelated to the code that caused the corruption and gives you no hint whatsoever where the bug is located.

There is very little joy in debugging this, it typically takes a thorough code review, lots of unit tests on the unmanaged code and days of debugging to find it.  The "crashes only in the debug build" scenario is very common as well, it doesn't mean that there is no heap corruption in the release build.  You are a bit lucky that it fails like this, heap corruption is *way* harder to debug when it occurs in the release build.  You'll want to invest in a debug allocator to catch the bug in action, like the one you get out of `<crtdbg.h>`.  This problem in general made garbage collectors a favored way to manage memory.

My condolences and good luck with it.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, this time you are not correct. After a long time debugging my application, I created a small application using only "new project" wizards that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: No repro at all.  Tested with VS2012 Update 1 on Win8 RTM with .NET 4.5 RTM.  If this crashes on your machine then look for an environmental problem.

Comment: I have win7 SP1 with the latest updates installed. What you are saying is interesting... I will test it in a VM

Comment: Any ideas about what it might be?